# Laravel migrations for testing suite

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

When I run the below command locally it should refresh my `testing` database using the latest seeders however it runs on my `app` database.

`php artisan migrate:fresh --seed --env=testing`

I have also tried

`php artisan --env=testing migrate:fresh --seed`

I have 2 env files, `.env` and `.env.testing`.

Each of these files contain their own database settings (all the same except for `DB_DATABASE`).

**.env**:

```
##
# DB
##
DB_CONNECTION="mysql"
DB_DATABASE="app"
DB_HOST="mysql"
DB_USERNAME="app"
DB_PASSWORD="***"
DB_PORT="3306"
```

**.env.testing**:

```
##
# DB
##
DB_CONNECTION="mysql"
DB_DATABASE="testing"
DB_HOST="mysql"
DB_USERNAME="app"
DB_PASSWORD="***"
DB_PORT="3306"
```

Can anyone advise why the artisan command is not listening to the `--env` flag and refreshing my main database instead?